# openCV: Entry Point not found using InstallShield Limited

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

i'm trying to create an installer for my opencv project. The Projects runs just fine, no error while compiling or at runtime. 
And i need the program to run on other machines as well, so i thought of making an installer. I've read that MS VS 2013 has discontinued the Deployment tool and so i am using *InstallShied Limited*.

I'm setting everything according to their tutorial and i am adding the opencv libs, it builds and i can install my application. But as soon as install it on other machine i get the following errer message:

**The procedure entry point _except1 could not be located in the dynamic link library opencv_imgproc.dll**

I also get this error if i just copy the dll files to another machine along with the exe file. Does this mean, that the dlls are not compatible with the system? i am using windows 8.1 on both machines. and its also weird that it runs when i build it from VS.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

regards, 
hh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: i had the 64bit dlls included  and runnning on 32bit. The 32 Bit dlls are in vc10